# fiddler to capture https

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, fiddler

I am using fiddler core API in c# to capture all traffic, the problem is when I am opening internet explorer for some secured website then its showing "**this page can’t be displayed**". but for some other https website, it's working in the same browser.

i am using following code:

```
    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;


    const FiddlerCoreStartupFlags flags =
        FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.AllowRemoteClients |
        FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.CaptureLocalhostTraffic |
        FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL |
        FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.MonitorAllConnections |
        FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy;

    FiddlerApplication.Startup(7777, flags);
```

// beforeRequest session code is:

```
   if (oSession.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod == "CONNECT")
                {
                    //oSession["x-no-decrypt"] = "do not care.";
                    return;
                }
                oSession.bBufferResponse = true;
                oSession.utilDecodeRequest();
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure the event handlers are set properly?

Comment: Have you turned on the https traffic from the Fiddler options? I do not think it is set as a default. In addition, you may need to export a certificate from fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. its working for some of the https url such as https://www.appneura.com  but not for other https website . before statrting session I am installing certifacate using following code:

public static bool UninstallCertificate()
{
    if (CertMaker.rootCertExists())
    {
        if (!CertMaker.removeFiddlerGeneratedCerts(true))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Comment: It could depend on the actual protocol being used.

Comment: when I am giving

 if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") )
    { 
        oSession["x-no-decrypt"] = "do not care."; 
    }

then browser is opening but not captering any session

Comment: can you please suggest any solution.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Or should I say... do you get the same results with different browsers?

Comment: no but I need to use only in  Internet explorer

Comment: It may help identify if its a code problem in fiddler or a browser setting. Just a suggestion. And it would be easy to check. I have seen different browsers work when explorer will not.

Comment: its comming for chrome also  means something problem with code. but I am not able to find.